# IDA Pro debugger hit counter

Tags: ida, debuggers, hit-counter

I'm looking for a way to found out how many times instruction at specified address was executed before break point hit.

Is there some standard way? I cannot found this in its interface.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I don't have IDA available to try it out right now, so a detail might be wrong.

Just add some code to the breakpoint condition. For example

```
extern bpcount;
bpcount++;
Message(form("%d. hit\n"), bpcount);
return (bpcount>500);
```

This will increment the count each time the breakpoint is it, but only break the program after more than 500 hits. Replace the return instruction with `return 0` if you never want to break, or `return 1` if you always want to break.

Comment: Well, it always prints "0. hit".

Answer (score 2):

Apparently IDA 7.0 (and earlier?) supports a "pass count" for a breakpoint, you can even see a column for that in the breakpoint list window, but I found no way to configure it via the UI.

You can use the following Python commands to create a breakpoint with a pass count though, where `0x12345678` is the address at which you want to set it, and `42` the hit count:

```
add_bpt(0x12345678, 1, BPT_DEFAULT)
set_bpt_attr(0x12345678, BPTATTR_COUNT, 42)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `Python` script on a breakpoint.

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\T3\\Desktop\\Count.txt', 'r+')
strData = f.readline()
n = int(strData)
n = n + 1
f.seek(0)
f.write(str(n))
f.close()
return 0
```

`Count` file at the beginning contained `0` but after execution it contains hit count.

---

This way has one drawback. File IO is slow, so registry counters may be used because it is stored in memory (that is only for Windows).