# IDA breakpoint condition

Tags: ida, breakpoint

How to set breakpoint condition that checks certain address value, for example:
0xD526C122 = FF.

How can I make a counter that counts how many times breakpoint condition was met without actually breaking the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify breakpoint conditions from Debugger -> Breakpoints -> Breakpoint List, selecting a breakpoint that you wish to edit, and pressing Ctrl + E. IDA provides some information on modifying breakpoints (incl. conditions):

- [IDA Help: Edit breakpoints](https://hex-rays.com//products/ida/support/idadoc/1407.shtml)
- [IDA Help: Breakpoint conditions](https://hex-rays.com//products/ida/support/idadoc/1488.shtml)

In your case, the condition would amount to `get_dword(0xD526C122) == 0xFF`.

As for the counter, this has been asked before in [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/ida-pro-debugger-hit-counter). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that there's a native way to do this in IDA, but you can do it easily by using some IDC and breakpoint conditions, as the top comment points out. Do note that their answer doesn't work properly due to bad ordering of the brackets, so I'll post a working solution here:

```
extern bpcount;
bpcount++;
Message(form("%d. hit\n", bpcount));
return (bpcount>500);
```